# where are category NAMES stored in magento?

Tags: magento, categories

Seems like this should be a findable question but I could not locate it.

Where is the category NAME stored in the magento database?  I can see `catalog_category_entity` has the key ID, and then there are the other EAV tables.  But I cannot find the actual name of the category stored in any table prefixed by `catalog_category`.

At least with products the catalog_products_entity table has the SKU (some human-readable value) in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The categories names are in the table `catalog_category_entity_varchar`

The request you are looking for :

```
select cat.*, cv.value as `category_name` from `catalog_category_entity` as cat
    join `catalog_category_entity_varchar` as cv on cat.entity_id = cv.`entity_id`
    join `eav_attribute` as att on att.`attribute_id` = cv.`attribute_id`
    join `eav_entity_type` as aty on att.`entity_type_id` = aty.`entity_type_id`
    where aty.`entity_model` = 'catalog/category' and att.`attribute_code` = 'name' and cv.`store_id` = 0
```

Please note that this is the name of your categories for your default store view.
If you do have multiple store or store view in your magento you just have to adapt the condition `` cv.`store_id` = 0 ``.
The list of your stores can be found in the table `core_store`

Answer (score 2):

'name' is an EAV attribute of type VARCHAR so you can find the values for that attribute on the `catalog_category_entity_varchar` table, but it contains all values for attributes that are type VARCHAR, so to query for only the values for the name attribute you have to find what the attribute id is, which you can find in that `eav_attributes` table using something like:

```
SELECT * FROM  `eav_attribute` WHERE  `entity_type_id` = ##CATEGORY ENTITY TYPE ID## AND  `attribute_code` =  'name'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ID's with you then this works:

SELECT DISTINCT `value`, `entity_id` FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` WHERE `entity_id` IN (ID's of the category) AND `attribute_id` = 111 AND `STORE` = 0

Make sure to replace "ID's of the category" with ID's seperated by commmas and Store ID too. ) is default Store ID.